# Mac Catalyst textfield first responder

Tags: ios, textfield, first-responder, mac-catalyst

On Mac Catalyst my app feature with textfield becomeFirstResponder() doesn't work. I try to put this code in viewwillappear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    workoutExerciseNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

}
```

I also tried to use:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
        workoutExerciseNameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

But this also doesn't work. Cell is twinkle for some time with selection and then twinkle out.

If I run my app in iOS it works as it should, but on Mac becomeFirstResponder() doesn't work.

How I can make textfields become firstresponder on Mac Catalyst versions of ios apps?

Comment: Is there any other code that deals with resigning first responder status anywhere in your view controller?

Comment: I disabled all resignFirstResponder(), but anyway it doesn't work.

Comment: I think there is no concept of  becomeFirstResponder

Answer (score 0):

Are there any ListViews?    In my app, they seem to become firstREsponder  after a selection, and then don't let go.  I force it to relinquish control in the `didselect:` method.